# HTML page elongate based on contents

Tags: html

I'm building a site with php, html and css. I mostly write in the space I've defined as mainContent which looks like this:

```
.mainContent{
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 74%;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 95px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I also have a footer that looks like:

```
.footer{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 87.2%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

However, whenever I type enough that the page requires scrolling, the text continues past the end of the mainContent block and under the footer block. Is there anyway to make it so the mainContent block expands downward [leaving a little bit of space after the text ends] and that the footer block moves down as well?

Thanks

Comment: you would get more help if you provide a testcase of your problem in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

remove the "height" from the mainContent

Comment: You'll also need to remove the `position:absolute;` tags here.  It looks like you want to have the `mainContent` be most of the page height and then have the footer at the end.  Consider using `min-height:600px;` to have `mainContent` take up a minimum amount of space.